# Custom Git Authorization Url?

Tags: node.js, git, tortoisesvn, tortoisegit

I'm playing around with a custom git server in node.js and am curious how login screens are displayed when using applications such as TortoiseGit.  Is there some standardized auth url and auth token or auth url and auth credentials format involved in this protocol which triggers things such as a web browser login when no credentials are found?

Comment: Git does not do any authorization or authentication at all. Git will, on occasion, run *other programs* that might do that (credential helpers and pgp/gpg), but Git doesn't do it itself. Git doesn't have an HTTP server either; you plug it into your existing server. Git expects that existing server to do the authentication. All of this lies outside Git.

Comment: @torek is there a generalized spec which matches tortoise git and other git clients?

Comment: Not as far as I know. All large sites (GitHub, GitLab, etc) build their own. GitLab do offer a "kit" of sorts that you can set up on your own servers, though.

Comment: @torek right, but how do you tell the git client to pull up that github, gitlab, bitbucket, etc login page from the git server?

Comment: You don't do anything special. When Git is connecting *as* a client, it just makes an https connection as usual, and the server just demands authentication as usual (through SSL and requiring authentication). There's nothing Git-ish here, it works the same as any authentication. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication for an overall description.